# ActionScript JPGEncoder +bad quality of the image

Tags: actionscript-3

I have noticed that the quality of the images produced by the JPEGEncoder does not match that of other encoders available (i.e. php's built in image compression functions from the gd library)

Any explanation ? or hints/workarounds for improving the quality of compressed images by JPEGEncoder ??

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's actionscript....

Look into the alchemy port of libjpeg, I heard it not only is faster to encode, but produces smaller and higher quality images.

http://segfaultlabs.com/devlogs/alchemy-asynchronous-jpeg-encoding

Answer (score 0):

You could try increasing the 'quality' setting passed to the JPEG encoder...higher numbers give higher quality, at the cost of higher filesize.

Answer (score 0):

As already suggested, try setting a higher quality level in the JPEG encoder.

Another option, if you don't absolutely need JPG, would be using PNGEncoder instead, which is lossless. For photographic images, JPG generally gives smaller files, though, but PNG could work just fine.